# Resize by fixed value using CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using CSS `resize:both;` property to let users resize my content. See the code below.

```css
.foo {
    resize: both;
    min-width: 250px;
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #515151;
    border-radius: 6px;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.33);
    box-shadow: 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0, 0.1);
}
.thClass {
    margin-left: -3px;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
    margin-top: -2px;
    min-height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 19px;
    cursor: move;
}
.header{
    margin-left: 17px;
}
.tableBody {
    display: block;
    min-height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 102%;
    margin-left: -2px;
    cursor: default;
}
.foo tbody tr td {
    display: block;
    line-height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
#displaySizes {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
}
.disp tbody tr th {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.disp tbody tr td {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<table class="foo disp elementTable">
                <tr class="tableHeader">
                    <th class="thClass" colspan="5">
                        <span class="header">Device</span>
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="4" id="sizeContainer">
                        <ul id="displaySizes">
                            <li>4:3</li>
                            <li>16:9</li>
                            <li>Clock</li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                    <td>$100</td>
                    <td>February</td>
                    <td>February</td>
                    <td>February</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>February</td>
                    <td>February</td>
                    <td>February</td>
                    <td>February</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>February</td>
                    <td>February</td>
                    <td>February</td>
                    <td>February</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>February</td>
                    <td>February</td>
                    <td>February</td>
                    <td>February</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Is there a way to resize this table step by step using CSS, for example, by [10,10] pixels? JavaScript is also OK. I've searched the web, but could not find anything. Here is the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vaxobasilidze/b996809u/2/) for you to play with code.

Comment: You want the table to resize at a set rate other than the drag motion of the user? If so that will be confusing as ballz to the user as it will seem like the resizing is lagging if it is not in sync with the user's drag motion.

Comment: @Fran Agree, that might seem weird. But the reason I want to do this is that I'll have a grid, and I don't want these tables to ruin the view. So if my grid is for example 100x100 pixels, I'll set the step [100,100] and the grid will be nice looking.

Comment: I think you've got it working nicely already, especially from a user point-of-view.  If you want to snap the size then snap the size *after* a resize, rather than during.  That will look a lot nicer to the user and also give you what you're after.

Comment: hmm, using min/max width/height and CSS, including CSS triggering at specific dimensions should work fine. That way you can apply a unique set of styles at specific sizes even if you want.

Comment: here is the fiddle for your query [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ydTCZ/)

Comment: @RadiantAhmed Check the OP's example link - it's already a lot more than that.

Comment: @RadiantAhmed That is jenky when you start clicking to close to the edges after resize.

Comment: @Fran he can even try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CU585/)

Comment: @Archer That's a good idea. I'll try to implement this on later level of development, because currently it needs some more work to be done before.

Comment: @Archer i agree with you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a good point , So It's possible using the [css-element-queries](https://github.com/marcj/css-element-queries) Library ,
All you have is creating a `ResizeSensor()` for your table and then make calculation to set both height and width range change :

See below Snippet :

```js
var width = $('.elementTable').width();
var height = $('.elementTable').height();
var changePX = 50;


new ResizeSensor(jQuery('.elementTable'), function(){ 

    //width calcuation 
    if(Math.abs($('.elementTable').width()-width) > changePX) {
      $('.elementTable').width() > width ? width +=changePX : width -=changePX;
    }
    $('.elementTable').width(width);
    
    //height calcuation 
    if(Math.abs($('.elementTable').height()-height) > changePX) {
      $('.elementTable').height() > height ? height +=changePX : height -=changePX;
    }
    $('.elementTable').height(height);
    
})
```

```css
.foo {
    resize: both;
    min-width: 250px;
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #515151;
    border-radius: 6px;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.33);
    box-shadow: 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0, 0.1);
}
.thClass {
    margin-left: -3px;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
    margin-top: -2px;
    min-height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 19px;
    cursor: move;
}
.header{
    margin-left: 17px;
}
.tableBody {
    display: block;
    min-height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 102%;
    margin-left: -2px;
    cursor: default;
}
.foo tbody tr td {
    display: block;
    line-height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
#displaySizes {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
}
.disp tbody tr th {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.disp tbody tr td {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/css-element-queries/0.4.0/ResizeSensor.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/css-element-queries/0.4.0/ElementQueries.min.js"></script>
<table class="foo disp elementTable">
                <tr class="tableHeader">
                    <th class="thClass" colspan="5">
                        <span class="header">Device</span>
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="4" id="sizeContainer">
                        <ul id="displaySizes">
                            <li>4:3</li>
                            <li>16:9</li>
                            <li>Clock</li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                    <td>$100</td>
                    <td>February</td>
                    <td>February</td>
                    <td>February</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>February</td>
                    <td>February</td>
                    <td>February</td>
                    <td>February</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>February</td>
                    <td>February</td>
                    <td>February</td>
                    <td>February</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>February</td>
                    <td>February</td>
                    <td>February</td>
                    <td>February</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Comment: Strange, but this function does not work in my application. I have included those script files and copied the function, but ResizeSensor does not get triggered. Any thoughts?

Comment: can you create a fiddle , or something like using this files .

Comment: Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vaxobasilidze/cvkatuhw/1/ Drag any item to the right container and resize it.

Comment: this is because you attaching resizeSensor to non existing .foo clas element , so I create a function to attach resizeSensor every drop on the mainDiv here is updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/cvkatuhw/2/

Comment: Wow, how could I miss that? :D Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution I put together that will snap to given grid on resize (in this example 20px.)

It uses "cross browser resize event listener", that a another developer has put together ([source](http://www.backalleycoder.com/2013/03/18/cross-browser-event-based-element-resize-detection/)):

Basically it just listens to the resize event, then sets the styles for width and height using javascript.

**Fiddle here:**

https://jsfiddle.net/treetop1500/co8zbatz/

```
// utility function for rounding (20px in this case)
function round20(x)
{
    return Math.ceil(x/20)*20;
}

// Attach listener
var myElement = document.getElementById('resize'),
    myResizeFn = function(){
        h = round20(parseInt(this.style.height,10));
        w = round20(parseInt(this.style.width,10));
        this.style.height = h + "px";
        this.style.width = w + "px";
    };

addResizeListener(myElement, myResizeFn);
```

Comment: Good and optimized function. Thanks!

Comment: Can you take a look at this fiddle please? https://jsfiddle.net/vaxobasilidze/ryxks2ob/ drop any item to the right and resize. your code does not work. Can you help me fix the problem? I have packed resize listener into a function and I call it when the item gets dropped.